# What does the dot syntax mean in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

I am just studying [this matplotlib example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21688791), but don't understand the dot syntax:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
class DraggablePoint:
    lock = None #only one can be animated at a time
    def __init__(self, point):
        self.point = point
        self.press = None
        self.background = None

    def connect(self):
        'connect to all the events we need'
        self.cidpress = self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.cidrelease = self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_release)
        self.cidmotion = self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)

    def on_press(self, event):
        if event.inaxes != self.point.axes: return
        if DraggablePoint.lock is not None: return
        contains, attrd = self.point.contains(event)
        if not contains: return
        self.press = (self.point.center), event.xdata, event.ydata
        DraggablePoint.lock = self

        # draw everything but the selected rectangle and store the pixel buffer
        canvas = self.point.figure.canvas
        axes = self.point.axes
        self.point.set_animated(True)
        canvas.draw()
        self.background = canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.point.axes.bbox)

        # now redraw just the rectangle
        axes.draw_artist(self.point)

        # and blit just the redrawn area
        canvas.blit(axes.bbox)

    def on_motion(self, event):
        if DraggablePoint.lock is not self:
            return
        if event.inaxes != self.point.axes: return
        self.point.center, xpress, ypress = self.press
        dx = event.xdata - xpress
        dy = event.ydata - ypress
        self.point.center = (self.point.center[0]+dx, self.point.center[1]+dy)

        canvas = self.point.figure.canvas
        axes = self.point.axes
        # restore the background region
        canvas.restore_region(self.background)

        # redraw just the current rectangle
        axes.draw_artist(self.point)

        # blit just the redrawn area
        canvas.blit(axes.bbox)

    def on_release(self, event):
        'on release we reset the press data'
        if DraggablePoint.lock is not self:
            return

        self.press = None
        DraggablePoint.lock = None

        # turn off the rect animation property and reset the background
        self.point.set_animated(False)
        self.background = None

        # redraw the full figure
        self.point.figure.canvas.draw()

    def disconnect(self):
        'disconnect all the stored connection ids'
        self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidpress)
        self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidrelease)
        self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidmotion)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
drs = []
circles = [patches.Circle((0.32, 0.3), 0.03, fc='r', alpha=0.5),
               patches.Circle((0.3,0.3), 0.03, fc='g', alpha=0.5)]

for circ in circles:
    ax.add_patch(circ)
    dr = DraggablePoint(circ)
    dr.connect()
    drs.append(dr)

plt.show()
```

Now take for example the line

`ax.add_patch(circ)`

This seems to be pretty clear to me. The `axes` class has a method called `add_patch` which takes (in particular) `Circle` objects as argument. So `ax.add_patch(circ)` just calls this method from the object `ax` which is an `axes` instance.

The dot in `import matplotlib.patches` seems to have a different meaning. It just accesses the module `patches` which is a submodule of `matplotlib` see http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/py-modindex.html for a list of modules.

And a module as I understand it is just a Python file containing some classes and functions.

Now consider:

`self.cidpress = self.point.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)`

`self.point` is the `point` variable defined in init (which doesn't need to be a fixed type). Later in the code there are `DraggablePoint` objects instantiated via `dr = DraggablePoint(circ)` where `circ` is a `patches.Circle` object. Now I struggle to interpret `self.point.figure`. The `figure` in this case cannot be a function since there is no `()` at the end.

For me it also doesn't make sense to see it as module in this case. I guess it is a type of shorthand for something like `self.point.get_current_figure()` which returns the figure where the point is drawn on.

Similarly the `self.point.figure.canvas` seems to be something like `self.point.get_current_figure().get_canvas()` which returns the current canvas. However there seems to be no `get_current_figure` or `get_canvas` methods in the `mathplotlib.patches.Circ` class resp. the `mathmatplotlib.figure.Figure` class (see:
http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/artist_api.html#module-matplotlib.patches and http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure).

So it would be great if someone could clarify this for me. And more generally:

- There seems to be multiple different meanings of dot notation in Python. Which are there, how are they called and how do I know which one is used?
- How can I see that I can call `self.point.figure` or `self.point.figure.canvas` from the matplotlib API docs? As noted above I didn't find it in the docs.

Comment: removed matplotlib tag because this is general python syntax and is not specific to maplotlib at all.

Comment: and the very short answer to your question is `a.b` <-> `getattr(a, 'b')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.` is just accessing an attribute. The attribute could be a class, an instance, a method/function, etc. When you see something like `a.b.c`, it is referring to the attribute `c` of attribute `b` of `a`, where `a`, `b`, and `c` could be any of the types mentioned above. In other words, it is attribute `c` of `a.b`.

The fact that there was no `()` at the end does *not* mean that the attribute isn't a function. Consider the following:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         import os
...         self.number = 1
...         self.module = os
...         self.class_ = Exception
...         self.function = dir
... 
>>> f = Foo()
```

A module can be an attribute:

```
>>> f.module
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
>>> f.module.path.join('foo', 'bar')
'foo/bar'
```

A class can be an attribute:

```
>>> f.class_
<type 'exceptions.Exception'>
>>> raise f.class_('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: foo
```

A function can be an attribute:

```
>>> f.function
<built-in function dir>
>>> f.function('.')
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

If you want to know whether you can call something, use the `callable` function:

```
>>> callable(f.module)
False
>>> callable(f.function)
True
```

If you want to know what an attribute is or how it is used, start by using the `help` function to read its doc string. For example:

```
help(f.function)
```

Comment: Thanks. How is it in the case of my `self.point.figure.canvas` example? `callable(circ.figure)` returns `false` just typing `circ.figure` returns nothing (after importing the right things and defining `circ`)

Comment: If it shows nothing, then it may be equal to `None`. Try typing `type(circ.figure)`.

Comment: `self` is the `DraggablePoint` object. `self.point` is the `point` argument that was passed to the constructor. `self.point.figure` is the matplotlib figure that is associated with the `point` argument. And `self.point.figure.canvas` is the canvas attribute of the figure that is an attribute of the point that was passed to the `DraggablePoint` constructor.

Comment: Yes, but **how** is "the matplotlib figure" associated with the `point` argument. And where is this association documented. As I wrote in my original post, I didn't find it in the docs...

Comment: It is added when you call `add_patch`, which is when it becomes associated with a figure. I don't know where/if it is stated in the public API that it is set when you add the patch to the figure.  If you want info on the attributes of a `Patch` object (including the `figure` attribute), start [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch).

Comment: Thanks I have seen it when browsing the code on: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/master/lib/matplotlib In the `artist.Artist` class there is a variable `figure` (i.e. the attribute figure) which is initially set to `None` the class `patches.Patch` is derived from `artist.Artist` and so `patches.Circle` however none of those subclasses defines `figure` to another value than `None`. However there is a method `set_figure()` in `artist.Artist`. And this method is called when you call `ax.add_patch(patch)` from an `axes` object `ax` ...

Comment: ...see: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/d3169046508a40a36c50660e91a4e5c2e9948b85/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py So I confirmed from the source code what you said.

Comment: And indeed in http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch there is a `property` called `figure`. However I was confused by the sentence: `The following kwarg properties are supported`