# move facial landmarks using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, events, alignment, face

tried to include your suggestions, not sure why it doesn't work:

```
# face alignment

import face_alignment
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io

# Run the 3D face alignment on a test image, without CUDA.
fa = face_alignment.FaceAlignment(face_alignment.LandmarksType._2D, device='cpu', flip_input=True)

input = io.imread(r'C:/Users/Ihr Name/Pictures/Bewerbungsfotos/neuropic.jpg')
preds = fa.get_landmarks(input)[-1] 

#landmarks == preds, input = pixels image


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

class DraggablePoints(object):
    def __init__(self, artists, tolerance=5):
        for artist in artists:
            artist.set_picker(tolerance)
        self.artists = artists
        self.currently_dragging = False
        self.current_artist = None
        self.offset = (0, 0)

        for canvas in set(artist.figure.canvas for artist in self.artists):
            canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
            canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_release)
            canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick)
            canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)

    def on_press(self, event):
        self.currently_dragging = True

    def on_release(self, event):
        self.currently_dragging = False
        self.current_artist = None

    def on_pick(self, event):
        if self.current_artist is None:
            self.current_artist = event.artist
            x0, y0 = event.artist.center
            x1, y1 = event.mouseevent.xdata, event.mouseevent.ydata
            self.offset = (x0 - x1), (y0 - y1)

    def on_motion(self, event):
        if not self.currently_dragging:
            return
        if self.current_artist is None:
            return
        dx, dy = self.offset
        self.current_artist.center = event.xdata + dx, event.ydata + dy
        self.current_artist.figure.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(.5))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
    ax.imshow(input)
    ax.plot(preds[0:17,0],preds[0:17,1],marker='o',markersize=6,linestyle='-',color='w',lw=2)
    ax.plot(preds[17:22,0],preds[17:22,1],marker='o',markersize=6,linestyle='-',color='w',lw=2)
    ax.plot(preds[22:27,0],preds[22:27,1],marker='o',markersize=6,linestyle='-',color='w',lw=2)
    ax.plot(preds[27:31,0],preds[27:31,1],marker='o',markersize=6,linestyle='-',color='w',lw=2)
    ax.plot(preds[31:36,0],preds[31:36,1],marker='o',markersize=6,linestyle='-',color='w',lw=2)
    ax.plot(preds[36:42,0],preds[36:42,1],marker='o',markersize=6,linestyle='-',color='w',lw=2)
    ax.plot(preds[42:48,0],preds[42:48,1],marker='o',markersize=6,linestyle='-',color='w',lw=2)
    ax.plot(preds[48:60,0],preds[48:60,1],marker='o',markersize=6,linestyle='-',color='w',lw=2)
    ax.plot(preds[60:68,0],preds[60:68,1],marker='o',markersize=6,linestyle='-',color='w',lw=2) 
    ax.axis('off')

    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d')
    surf = ax.scatter(preds[:,0]*1.2,preds[:,1],preds[:,2],c="cyan", alpha=0.5, edgecolor='b')
    ax.plot3D(preds[:17,0]*1.2,preds[:17,1], preds[:17,2], color='blue' )
    ax.plot3D(preds[17:22,0]*1.2,preds[17:22,1],preds[17:22,2], color='blue')
    ax.plot3D(preds[22:27,0]*1.2,preds[22:27,1],preds[22:27,2], color='blue')
    ax.plot3D(preds[27:31,0]*1.2,preds[27:31,1],preds[27:31,2], color='blue')
    ax.plot3D(preds[31:36,0]*1.2,preds[31:36,1],preds[31:36,2], color='blue')
    ax.plot3D(preds[36:42,0]*1.2,preds[36:42,1],preds[36:42,2], color='blue')
    ax.plot3D(preds[42:48,0]*1.2,preds[42:48,1],preds[42:48,2], color='blue')
    ax.plot3D(preds[48:,0]*1.2,preds[48:,1],preds[48:,2], color='blue' )


    ax.view_init(elev=90., azim=90.)
    ax.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim()[::-1])

#we want to move preds (landmarks)

    for p in preds:
        ax.add_patch(p)
        dr = DraggablePoints(preds)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draggable line with draggable points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001655/draggable-line-with-draggable-points)

Comment: thanks, but not sure how I can relate that to my script.

Comment: As it stands, I don't think anybody will be able to help with your problem. People need to be able to run your code to know what's going on. Without the data that goes alongside your code, it's pretty hard to try and figure out anything.

Comment: However, you are working with 3D axes, which will require to change the `DraggablePoint` class accordingly. Then you do `for p in pred: ax.add_patch(p)` but p is not a patch, you need to create a [`patches` object](https://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html) first. However, dealing with patches in 3D is troublesome: https://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html